# Access to pfsense wan interface by ip public

Tags: iptables, firewall, pfsense

I have this diagram.
[image]

I have a server(`centos 7`) with `ip public and staic 1.2.3.4` on internet, I want when user send request to this public ip 1.2.3.4, this request pass my modem with not static ip address and then route to `pfsenes`.

What routing do I need in `IPTable`? (centos 1.2.3.4).

What routing do I need in `PFsense`?

I think I need to setup something like ssh tunnel on pfsense. But I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Google search for dynamic DNS. That can help achieve your goal

Comment: I used Cloudflare Arog tunnel.